# One line logical test to check existence of all items of one list in the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to write a single line logical test to check the existence of all items in one list in the other.

I tried the **contains**() method but it only works with single value, and always return False when I use a list:

```py
        keys = ['key1', 'key2']
        list = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
        list.__contains__(keys)
```

It should return True in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']).issuperset(['key1', 'key2'])
```

or

```
{'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}.issuperset(['key1', 'key2'])
```

or

```
{'key1', 'key2', 'key3'} >= {'key1', 'key2'}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works as described. However, I'm trying to apply it to column names of a data frame and using .columns.to_list().issuperset returns an error indicating it doesn't have a issuperset() method. Any work around?

Comment: Yes, convert the list to a set, as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

result =  all(elem in list  for elem in keys)